# Activate chrome.notifications object on Chrome

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, notifications

I wanted to try and use the `chrome.notifications` api on Chrome (using Windows and Chrome 40+, so the API is supported). The only problem is that the object simply does not exist when trying to use. The type of `chrome.notifications` is undefined, and obviously if I try to use `chrome.notifications.create`, I get an error "cannot read property create of undefined".

The thing is, I have activated notifications, and I'm using pushbullet with my android phone, which uses this rich notifications feature, and it works perfectly.

So is `chrome.notifications` reserved for chrome apps?

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I think `chrome.notifications` is chrome plugin only, but you can use the ["standard" `Notification` api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)

[Example usage:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification#Example)

```
function notifyMe() {
  // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
  }

  // Let's check if the user is okay to get some notification
  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // If it's okay let's create a notification
    var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
  }

  // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
  else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
      // If the user is okay, let's create a notification
      if (permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
      }
    });
  }

  // At last, if the user already denied any notification, and you 
  // want to be respectful there is no need to bother them any more.
}
```

> **This is an experimental technology**
>   Because this technology's specification has not stabilized, check the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification#Browser_compatibility) for the proper prefixes to use in various browsers. Also note that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject to change in future versions of browsers as the spec changes.

Comment: Yes,I have actually developed a mini library for it (github.com/jsmrcaga/miniNotif), but I wanted to make rich notifications from web without plugin. Pity you can't. Thank you very much ;) !